# Tikz: Coordinate names and definitions collide bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \def\switch_bottom{0.5}
    \coordinate (switch_bot) at (0, \switch_bottom);
    ...
```

I get an error saying "Unknown PGF function `ottom' (in 'ottom')

My suspicion was that tikz wasn't happy with the names of the coordinate and the `\def`, so simply renaming the variables so they were substrings of one another worked. E.g.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
      \def\switchBottom{0.5}
      \coordinate (switch_bot) at (0, \switchBottom);
```

Does anybody know why this bug happens?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Macro names cannot contain underscores. Nor with numbers and so on.

Comment: The syntax highlighting gives you a subtle hint: `\switch_bottom` is  not a macro with name `switch_bottom`. It calls a macro called `\switch` and then executes `_bottom`, which usually means you get into math mode and typeset a subscript 'b' and then  'ottom'. The easiest way out is to pick a macro name LaTeX is happy with. Those consist only of letters (very roughly).